# Passing variables from PHP to Javascript back to PHP using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I have a PHP page that contains variables, I have some radial boxes, and on click of them, it calculates a price for the item you have clicked on. I do this by activating a js function that I have passed some variables to. Like so.

PHP:

```
$result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Segments ORDER BY 'Squares'");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'query failed';
        exit;               
    }

    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    <span><?php echo $row["Squares"]; ?></span>
    <input name="squares" type="radio" 
        onclick="ajaxCases('<?php echo $row["Squares"]; ?>', '<?php echo $row["StartCaseID"]; ?>', '<?php echo $row["StartMatrixPrice"]; ?>')" value="<?php echo $row["Squares"]; ?>"
        <?php if ($row["Squares"] == "1") { ?> checked="checked" <?php }else{ ?> checked="" <?php } ?>/>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see onclick it goes to a function called ajaxcases, this function looks like this.

```
function ajaxCases(squares,start,price){
    $('#step1').html('<p style="margin:100px 0px 0px 100px"><img src="images/ajax-loader-bigindic.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></p>');
    $('#step1').load("ajax-styles.php?squares="+squares);
    prevId1 = "";
    document.varsForm.caseid.value=start;
    $('#step1price').html('<span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 30px"><img src="images/ajax-loader-price.gif" width="24" height="24" alt="" /></span>');
    $('#step1price').load("ajax-step1-price.php?Squares="+Squares);
    return true;
}
```

This then goes to a php page called ajax-step1-price.php and I try to recall the variable Squares. However it doesn't work, I thought it was a GET however that returns undefined.

In Summary: I would like to know how to pass a variable from PHP to JS then back to PHP, or if someone could just tell me where I am going wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

I am using  MS SQL DB.

Comment: Your code would be a lot cleaner if you moved your embedded styles into a CSS file and used a `class` or `id` attribute instead.  That is best practice for HTML/CSS anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your function signature.

You have:

```
function ajaxCases(squares,start,price){
```

Should be:

```
//                 |-------- capital S
function ajaxCases(Squares,start,price) {
```

Or better yet, change this:

```
$('#step1price').load("ajax-step1-price.php?Squares="+Squares);
```

To This:

```
//                                                    v--- lowercase s
$('#step1price').load("ajax-step1-price.php?Squares="+squares);
```

JavaScript variable are [case-sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity).

Comment: unless he's deliberately referring to a global variable that does not respect the naming convention. :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak :) yes that is true

Answer (score 0):

the Squares is indeed a GET variable, you can access it like this: `$_GET['Squares']`:

If `$_GET['Squares']` returns `undefined`, verify that you calling the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it.

First look into resulting HTML generated by PHP.

If all values are correct, try running the javascript generated for `<input name="squares" onclick="..." />` in browser console.

If the call from `ajaxCases()` goes to the server, look into the URL - whether it is correctly formed.

If it is - check what the server script returns and what it does with input values.

Hope that helps.